# memory footprint for asp.net core IConfiguration

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration

in asp.net core application when application starts, by default `IConfiguration` is filled is all the configuration data from appsettings, environment variable..to azure keyVault.

I have 500+ configuration data (most of them are from azure keyVault).

Question is - what is the memory footprint for it, does it remain all time in memory as long as applications runs, is this slow down the application performance?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the values is remain all time in the memory as long as the application runs, and it can make the process more robust and improve the application performance.

Generally, when the .net core application start, some service might be require this configuration data, so, it will read all the configuration data to configure, then, when you want to use it, you can get value from the Configuration variable. This approach makes the process more robust, such as using Dependency Injection (DI) to load a service with these values. Besides, about the KeyVault value, Secrets are cached until IConfigurationRoot.Reload() is called. Expired, disabled, and updated secrets in the key vault are not respected by the app until Reload is executed. More detail information, you can refer this articles:
[Azure Key Vault Configuration Provider in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
[Asp.net Core Store configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#store-configurations)

Comment: thanks @Zhi. Is `IConfigurationRoot.Reload() ` will does automatically if key vault values changed or we need to do it though some code/settings. Could you guide this furthur?